# TypeScript declaration file

Tags: typescript

I'm trying to do a word cloud using typescript, react, d3.

My console complains that d3-cloud from npm needs a declaration file, so I've come up with this:
EDIT3: Declaration file now looks like this, the same error message is given:

```
declare module 'd3-cloud' {
  export function cloud (): Function;
}
```

All I get now is this error:

> TS2349: Cannot invoke an expression whose type lacks a call signature. Type 'typeof 'd3-cloud'' has no compatible call signatures.

Thanks for any help!

EDIT: I might add that once I reload the page there is a flash of the rendered word cloud, right before the error message takes over. So it sorta works, but... That AT-loader is really unhappy.

EDIT2: I used the npm module like this:

```
import * as d3Cloud from 'd3-cloud'

const layout = d3Cloud()
  .size([width, height])
  .font(font)
  ...
```

Comment: Can you include how you used that module?

Comment: @E_net4 Added as EDIT2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the library you use directly exports a function you can type it like this:

```
declare module 'd3-cloud' {
  let cloud: Function;
  export = cloud;
}
```